# Selenium verify randomly generated email

Tags: forms, selenium, random, automation

I am building test cases for a particular website, where I need Selenium to fill out a registration form, Ive got it all set up, however my only issue is getting it to "Verify" the random email it entered in the original "Email" field.

I have everything else working but since I am somewhat of a noob at all this (Im just game Automation QA that needs to work on some website test cases) I am somewhat in over my head

```
javascript{'Username+'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)+'@gmail.com'}
```

This is the code I am using to generate the random email (and usernames)

So, pretty much, id like to know if its possible to store that email to use it in another field of the form I need it to fill in.

Thanks

Comment: Why cant u store it in some variable and use that for verification?  What is the code that you are using?  IDE or RC?

Comment: I'm using Selenium IDE

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Selenium `store` method to store that email address and then use it later.

```
store    javascript{'Username+'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)+'@gmail.com'}    random_email
```

And then you can later use it like this

```
verifyText    //span[@id=email]    ${random_email}
```

Here is the selenium reference about variables: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#store-commands-and-selenium-variables